# Killing Programs using the PGRP or PID

Tags: bash

I have some code in my .bash_profile that makes many numbered folders very quickly. Currently, I have it so that when it is finished, it echoes "Finished" every 0.5 seconds. How do I make it so that the program automatically gets the PGRP or PID of the program and then kills the PGRP or PID instead?

Comment: maybe store PID in a variable in the `.bash_profile` , like "process_pid", just below your code and kill it using `kill $process_pid` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant piece of your code - otherwise we can only really guess.